# What should I set to _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator

I was digging in the `std::vector::insert` implementation in MSVC 2013 and I found this code:

```
#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
        if (_VICONT(_Where) != this
            || _VIPTR(_Where) < this->_Myfirst
            || this->_Mylast < _VIPTR(_Where))
            _DEBUG_ERROR("vector insert iterator outside range");
        _DEBUG_RANGE(_First, _Last);
 #endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2 */
```

and it was disabled because `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL = 0` (Release Mode). If I switched to Debug Mode it become enabled because `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL = 2`.

**My questions are:**

1. Is this MSVC thing or it is a standard?
2. Why would someone make `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL = 0` even in Release Mode. Isn't an Undefined Behavior that should be caught rather than put on silent mode!? I mean if the condition that inside that block did satisfied, it may cause many problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Out of bounds insert has undefined behaviour according to standard, so yes, it is a MSVC thing.
2. Because it affects performance.